# How to check the rgb color of the object using if condition? help me

Tags: flash, actionscript, colors, rgb

I want to check the RGB color of the object using actionscript in flash. The name of the object is object1. I checked like this but it didnt worked. help me

```
if (object1.color=rgb(255,0,255))
{
  trace("Selected Pink");
}
```

Give me correct syntax to check the rgb color of the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comparison operator in Actionscript needs to "=" signs.

```
if (object1.color == rgb(255,0,255))
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you setting our objects color property? Is Color a String value? or a Number ex: 0xFF00FF.

Is rgb() a function that you created? or just pseudo code?
How do you want this comparison to work?